# Can't convert string to integer or double

Tags: excel, vba

This is the code:

```
Sub imagesize()
Dim selection As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim objShell As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Dim dimen As String
Dim xmm As Double
Dim ymm As Integer
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set selection = Application.selection

For Each rng In selection.Cells
    Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace("C:\Users\Desktop\")
    Set objFile = objFolder.ParseName("try.tif")
    dimen = objFile.ExtendedProperty("Dimensions")
    xmm = Val(Left(dimen, InStr(dimen, "x") - 2))
    Cells(rng.Row, rng.Column).Value = xmm
Next rng
```

End Sub

I already get the dimensions of the picture, but I can't convert that string into integer, neither with `CInt` nor `Val`, but it only contains numbers. What am I missing here? Thanks for the answers.

Comment: http://www.dotnetperls.com/parse-vbnet

Comment: Would adding the picture with original size in the sheet and then reading the size from there will work for you?

Comment: Unfortunetly, that will not work in a long way. This is just a test, it will read hundreds of ver large pictures (600 dpi, tif), so this way seems to long and complacated. But anyway, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this line `xmm = Val(Left(dimen, InStr(dimen, "x") - 2))`

with following code

```
If dimen <> "" Then
    dimen = Mid(dimen, 2, Len(dimen) - 2)
    xmm = CDbl(Split(dimen, "x")(0))
    ymm =  CDbl(Split(dimen, "x")(1))
End If
```

Alternatively, you can just insert the image with original dimension and read the height and width from there. https://stackoverflow.com/a/39151519/3961708

Comment: Thank you,it's working. Can you tell me what i was doing wrong?

Comment: great. in your code, after instr you were  getting a string with `?` in it. when you do `Val` and the param string contains any non numeric character , `Val` fails. So e.g. `Val("?10")` will not work. So I just trimmed the dimen string to get rid of `?` chars from start and end. In VBA if the character is unreadable it gets converted to `?`